# using IIS self signed cert, but form data is still plain text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, https

I'm pretty newbie in https and my project is MVC web application and i've created a self-signed certificate in IIS and set the website's binding to use that certificate and ssl settings to 'require SSL' and I can browse the website over https (although it's not verified and has red x on it).

The part that I don't understand is when I send a request to server (post request), I can still check the network console and see what was the parameter passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can still check the network console

I assume that you mean the information about the send and received data within the browser with "network console". Since the browser is creating and encrypting the data the browser has access to the clear text before encryption and after decryption and thus can show these information.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I asummed the same but wanted to be sure. And the self signed certificate was for testing purposes. Will use a verified cert for it.